# Scala, how to use Some(value) from an Option implicitly?

Tags: scala

I have a piece of code that extracts a string from a request body, but it may not be there, so it is an `Option[String]`. If there is a value, then I wish to use it implicitly.

To do this conversion, I write `implicit val code = googleCode`.

Is there a way to make `googleCode` an *implicit* String so that I can use it directly rather than creating an `implicit val` with the value of `googleCode`?

```
    request.getQueryString("code") match {
      case None => 
        Logger.error("unable to retrieve authentication code from google request")
        Redirect(routes.Application.index())

      case Some(googleCode) => Async {
        implicit val code: String = googleCode // <== CONVERTING TO AN IMPLICIT
        Logger.debug("retrieved authentication code, proceeding to get token")
        ...
        Ok("congratulations, ${user.name}, you are logged in!")
```

Note, the code snippet is from a Playframework Controller, but this is more a question of the Scala language in general

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's often advisable to avoid using pattern matching with Options anyway. Here's how you can write it:

```
request.getQueryString("code") map { implicit googleCode =>
  // googleCode is an implicit String! do something with it
} getOrElse {
  // handle the None case
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that I should avoid using pattern matching with Options. I'm curious, could you explain the rationale or point me to a good link?

Comment: Instead of `.map(f).getOrElse(x)`, you can just use `.fold(x)(f)` these days.

Comment: @Alex http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option calls it less-idiomatic.

Comment: @copumpkin Thanks for pointing out the `fold` method -- glad to see that it was added to the API.

Comment: @Alex I don't think there's a technical reason to use a fold (i.e., `fold` or `map`/`getOrElse`). However, it does result in more concise code which, once you're familiar with the idioms of the language, is also more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Instead of looking for a solution for converting a code using Option into some kind of Java, I would suggest to take these three easy steps.

Step 1. Do whatever is the shortest cut for you, like option.get(), anything, so that your code (kind of) works.
Step 2. Learn functional programming. Specifically, learn to use Option in a idiomatic, specifically FP-style way. 
Step 3. Profit. You will benefit a lot from learning.

Comment: actually, your suggestion to do `option.get` would turn it into "some kind of Java" because `None.get` would throw a NoSuchElementException.

Comment: That's presumably why he put it under step 1, 'the shortest cut for you'.

Comment: The scala.Option cheat sheet is extremely useful: http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/